# setInterval stop at one percent

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to animate three counters simultaneously by `setInterval`.

The counters should stop at 10, 20, and 30 respectively, I have saved these numbers in an array `data`, and passed them into the parameter of `setInterval`, and then they should have stopped when the variable `counter1, counter2, counter3` is more than or equal to their number `10, 20, 30` by `clearInterval(this)`.

The problem is that they all stop at 1%, I don't know why...

```js
const data = ['10', '20', '30'],
  item = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  
let counter1 = 0,
  counter2 = 0,
  counter3 = 0;

function go(current, data, item) {
  if (current >= data) {
    clearInterval(this);
  } else {
    current++;
    item.textContent = current + '%';
  }
}

let go1 = setInterval(go, 10, counter1, data[0], item[0]),
  go2 = setInterval(go, 10, counter2, data[1], item[1]),
  go3 = setInterval(go, 10, counter3, data[2], item[2]);
```

```html
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
```

Comment: @NicoHaase I already give the example which I have tried and I told that all the counter stop at 1%.

Comment: The counters are passed by value, like all JavaScript parameters, so `counter++` in the timer callback won't affect the counter variables.

Comment: @Pointy I see, may I know how to solve the problem in this case?

Comment: I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter variables outside the callback will not be affected by `counter++` inside the callback. Instead, use an array of counters and pass in the *index* of the counter to examine.

```js
const data = ['10', '20', '30'],
  item = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  
let counters = [0, 0, 0];

function go(index, data, item) {
  if (counters[index] >= data) {
    clearInterval(this);
  } else {
    counters[index]++;
    item.textContent = counters[index] + '%';
  }
}

let go1 = setInterval(go, 10, 0, data[0], item[0]),
  go2 = setInterval(go, 10, 1, data[1], item[1]),
  go3 = setInterval(go, 10, 2, data[2], item[2]);
```

```html
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
```

It would also be possible to simplify so that you pass *only* the index, and then use it for the `data` and `item` arrays.

Comment: This is working but I don't understand why my initial try ( the counter variable `counter1` ) won't be affected by the callback `current++`, instead `counters[index]++` works. Any explanation on this, please?

Comment: @dejitay836 JavaScript is a *call by value* language. When you pass `counter1` to the function, the function just sees the initial value `0`.  The parameter variable in the function will contain a copy of that value. The `counter++` statement will work, but it will not affect `counter1`: only the `counter` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It can be simplified a lot by simply passing an index that will refer to `items` `data` and `counters` arrays.

```js
const data = [10, 20, 30],
  items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('test'));

let counters = [0, 0, 0]

function go(index) {
  if (counters[index] >= data[index]) {
    clearInterval(this);
  } else {
    items[index].textContent = ++counters[index] + '%';
  }
}

let intervals = items.map((item, index) => setInterval(go, 100, index))
```

```html
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `current` never changes because your interval callback will always be called with the *same* values. I would use `setTimeout` instead only calling `go` with updated arguments if `current <= data`.

```js
const data = ['10', '20', '30'];
const item = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  
let counter1 = 0;
let counter2 = 0;
let counter3 = 0;

function go(current, data, item) {
  if (current <= data) {
    item.textContent = current + '%';
    setTimeout(go, 10, ++current, data, item);
  }
}

go(counter1, data[0], item[0]);
go(counter2, data[1], item[1]);
go(counter3, data[2], item[2]);
```

```html
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
<p class="test">0</p>
```